# Corners ImageView fit inside CardView does not have radius like CardView's corners in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-cardview

I am developing an Android App. In my app I am using `CardView` and `ImageView` together. But I am having a problem in designing `ImageView` inside `CardView`. The problem is with corner radius radius of `ImageView`.

I have XML layout for adapter item like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/di_card_container"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/di_iv_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/di_iv_image"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/di_name_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                android:id="@+id/di_tv_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

As you can see I set, corner radius of `CardView` to `5dp` and the `ImageView` with is fit to the width of its parent `CardView`. The problem is both top corners of `ImageView` is not bent like its parent `CardView`'s corner.

This is the screenshot

[image]

Normally corners of child views of `CardView` automatically bent like its parent corners if it fit to parent `CardView`. Is that right? So why is my `ImageView` is not working?

Comment: Are you having this issue while testing on a pre lollipop device?

Comment: Yes. I am testing it on android 4.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this is a common behavior on pre lollipop. Here are the steps to fix it :

Step 1 : Add the following attributes to your cardView

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
```

Step 2 : Use a custom ImageView that rounds its top borders :

```
public class RoundedTopImageView extends ImageView {
private Paint                       mPaint;
private Path                        mPath;
private Bitmap                      mBitmap;
private Matrix                      mMatrix;
private int                         mRadius = DisplayUtils.convertDpToPixel(10);
private int                         mWidth;
private int                         mHeight;
private Drawable                    mDrawable;

public RoundedTopImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public RoundedTopImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public RoundedTopImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    mPath = new Path();
}

@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    mDrawable = drawable;
    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBitmap = drawableToBitmap(drawable);

    int bDIWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
    int bDIHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();

    //Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    if ((mHeight / (float)bDIHeight) >= (mWidth / (float)bDIWidth)){
        scale =  mHeight / (float)bDIHeight;
    } else {
        scale = mWidth / (float)bDIWidth;
    }

    float borderLeft = (mWidth - (bDIWidth * scale)) / 2;
    float borderTop = (mHeight - (bDIHeight * scale)) / 2;

    mMatrix = getImageMatrix();
    RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, bDIWidth, bDIHeight);
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(borderLeft, borderTop, (bDIWidth * scale) + borderLeft, (bDIHeight * scale) + borderTop);
    mMatrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    invalidate();
}

private Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    mWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    mHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    if ((mDrawable != null) && (mHeight > 0) && (mWidth > 0)) {
        setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (mBitmap == null) {
        return;
    }

    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(0, mRadius);
    mPath.lineTo(0, canvas.getHeight());
    mPath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    mPath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), mRadius);
    mPath.quadTo(canvas.getWidth(), 0, canvas.getWidth() - mRadius, 0);
    mPath.lineTo(mRadius, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(0, 0, 0, mRadius);


    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    canvas.clipPath(mPath);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mMatrix, mPaint);
}

}
```

Step 3 : Simply replace your ImageView in your xml with the RoundedTopImageView

Step 4 : Use this in your code as a regular imageView, for example with Picasso :

```
RoundedTopImageView image = (RoundedTopImageView) findViewById(R.id.di_iv_image);
Picasso.with(context)
                    .load("Some cool Url")
                    .into(image);
```

EDIT : Added the `convertDpToPixel` function

Sorry, I forgot to add this, which is part of a Util class that you can add anywhere you want (in my case in `DisplayUtils` class) :

```
public static int convertDpToPixel(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, displayMetrics);
}
```

Comment: Cannot find DisplayUtils class for DisplayUtils.convertDpToPixel(10). So please how can I get it?

Comment: It works well removing padding spaces but the top corners are not rounded with lint error stating `extend AppCompatImageView instead`

Comment: How about rounded top and bottom

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question like me..
If you're using Picasso, you can use [this transformations lib](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations) & use the following (in Kotlin):

```
val radius = 5
Picasso.get()
        .load(image)
        .fit()        // to centerCrop, you have to do either resize() or fit()
        .centerCrop() // to remove any possible white areas
        .transform(RoundedCornersTransformation(radius, 0,
                RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.TOP))
        .into(imageView)
```

I tried checking whether *radius* is px or dp, but could not find any resources. However, from my test, it should be dp. [The sample](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations/blob/7c2d5fed578c2100c3ba2ddb6923a92c95e399f7/example/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/example/picasso/MainAdapter.java#L270) also seems to suggest it's dp because there's no conversion done from dp to px.

The functions `fit()`, `centerCrop()` & `transform()` must be done in order.

If you're using Glide, a similar solution exists in [the Glide version of the lib](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations).

Answer (score -2):

Step1: add dependency in your App level build.gradle

```
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
```

Step2: in CardView xml Code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 

android:id="@+id/di_card_container"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
app:cardElevation="4dp">
```

Step3 in ImageView:

```
 <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
  android:id="@+id/di_iv_image"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  app:riv_corner_radius_top_left="5dp"                                     
  app:riv_corner_radius_top_right="5dp"/>
```

I hope It will help

Comment: This dependency just crops the photo in a wired way and make it look like crap